# ExtJs Blinking DisplayField using animate

Tags: animation, extjs, extjs-mvc

Afternoon everyone,

I have a displayfield and i would like to implement a constant blinking animation for it. I am still new to ExtJs and brand spanking new to animations. I have put together some code I found on the internet. I guess it is doing something because the text is no longer visible. I just need help tweaking it to make a blinking animation. Thanks.

```
{ xtype: 'displayfield', itemId:'txtTest', width:165, value:'Test' }

var p = sender.down('#txtTest');
p.animate({
   duration: 100,
    to: {
        opacity: 0
    }
});
```

Comment: Please don't do that. Blinkenlights can cause epileptic seizures: http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/#seizure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a animate function which calls itself

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lsl

```
function animate(target, opacityFrom, opacityTo) {
    var anim = Ext.create('Ext.fx.Anim', {
        target: target,
        duration: 1000,
        from: {
            opacity : opacityFrom
        },
        to: {    
            opacity : opacityTo
        }
    });
    anim.on("afteranimate", function() {
        if(opacityFrom == 1) {
            animate(target, 0, 1);             
        } else {
            animate(target, 1, 0);
        }

    }, this, {
        single : true
    });
}
```